# .Net5 vs .Net Core 3 Which one should I choose as a target

Tags: asp.net-core

I've started to develop a web project using asp.net core. When I opened project properties in VS2019 I noticed that it's default target framework is .net5 and not ".net core 3"? Why is that?
From what I've heard in recent years .net core is the new version of .net so why VS's default target framework is .net? Should I change it to .netcore 3 ?

Comment: `.NET 5` is the new name for the next version of `.net core` after 3.x. The naming is intended to be changed back to .net but with a new meaning of unifying all platforms in one framework. So that means `.net core` is just a temporary name for the transition from Windows-based .net to multi-platform .net. However we can use `.net core` and `.net 5` interchangeably without making any confusion. Finally (maybe after many years), we will just become familiar with the name `.NET` and forget about `.NET Core`, it's just the name and does not affect its ever growing power.

Comment: In addition .net 3.1 is LTS .net 5 is not. .net 6 suppose to become LTS as well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

.Net5 = .Net 5 Core

> .NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We named this new release .NET 5.0 instead of .NET Core 4.0 for two reasons:

> We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.x.
> We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5.0 supports more types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five

Comment: Thanks Microsoft for confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: they sure love to skip their version numbers, don't they 

Answer (score 7):

.Net5 = .Net 5 Core

**.NET 5 is the next generation of .NET Core**, which is a combination of previous technologies.

**You are operationally better off using .NET 5**. Because it has better speed and performance

Comment: Just to add, you're possibly better off skipping 5 altogether. I'd suggest it's worth staying with 3 until 6 tooling catches up if you're building production systems as there is no LTS for 5 and some packages (in my experience at least) aren't compatible with 5 so you have to revert to 3.

Answer (score 0):

**.Net5, .Net6** is a unified platform.

It means a collection/aggregation of **.Net Core**, **.Net Framework**, **Mono + Xamarin**, to develop any type of app for any platform.

**.Net5** is derived from **.Net Core** to develop fully open source application for any purpose.